# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.Model' in nopcommerce 4.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

This error throws me when I am pass data to the model and call the view.

Here is the full error shows,

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Castle.Proxies.VendorProxy', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Nop.Web.Models.Common.VendorDetailModel]'.**

Now, I create one model, one view and controller in nopcommerce 4.2.

Here is my model place,

**Nop.Web => Models => Common => VendorDetailModel**

Here is the code of mode

```
public VendorDetailModel()
{
    Address = new List<AddressModel>();
}
public string Name { get; set; }       

public IList<AddressModel> Address { get; set; }
```

Here is the controller placed

**Nop.Web => Controllers => CommonController => Vendordetail(method)**

Here is the controller code

```
public virtual IActionResult Vendordetail(int vendorId)
{
    var model = _vendorService.GetVendorById(vendorId);
    return View("Vendordetail",model);
}
```

Here is the view placed,

**Nop.Web => Views => Common => Vendordetail.cshtml**

Here is the view code

```
@model VendorDetailModel
content.......
```

So, this error is showing when I place the **@model VendorDetailModel** in view file while if I remove this line then error is not showing. But I remove this line then how can I get the value without model.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe at some point in your view, you are passing the wrong model to a partial view. In my case, my view was getting a model for "BOX", and using a partial view expecting a model for "ORDER" but I didn't explicitly pass the "ORDER" model to the partial, so the partial view was getting the default "BOX" model, which was wrong and was triggering this "Castle.model.proxy" error.

Answer (score -1):

I got the solution.

problem is that I didnt giving the value to the model, just passing the store data variable from controller to view.

Here is my solution code.

```
var model = new VendorDetailModel();
var vendor = _vendorService.GetVendorById(vendorId);
model.Name = vendor.Name;
return View(model);
```

**and view page is same as it is previous**